# Hiding map annotations without deleting them

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations, mapkit

Using a MKMapView I have a pile of annoatations loaded onto it and I want to be able to filter the annotations displayed with a segmented control.

I'm using custom annotations with a type variable so I can tell them apart from one another but I haven't been able to find a way to hide and display a subset of annotation views at will.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, try this:

**Objective-C** solution:

```
[[yourMapView viewForAnnotation:yourAnnotation] setHidden:YES]
```

**Swift 4** solution:

```
yourMapView.view(for: yourAnnotation)?.isHidden = true
```

This will return you the view associated with the specified annotation object, then you can set the view to hidden. Here is the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/viewForAnnotation:).

Comment: Thanks for that, worked a treat. Sorry for not getting back to this sooner.

Comment: When filtering is it better to hide the annotation or remove it?

Comment: this will hide until zoom/move map, not quite so, but unstable, in common

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the MKAnnotationView (bubble) you can create a custom one:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    if (annotation==self.map.mapView.userLocation)
        return nil;


    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"loc"];
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[AnnotationCustomClass class]] ) {
        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO; // <- hide the bubble

    }

    return annotationView;

}
```