# How to filter annotations on a map view

Tags: ios, filter, annotations, mapkit, android-mapview

I'm currently working on an application that displays annotations on the map. They have multiple colours that represent different things. For example green represents cafes and Purple is to represent museums. I would like to be able to have a button that filters the annotations so that all the purple show whilst the other colours stay hidden and vice versa.

Thanks in advance, Niall.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding map annotations without deleting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233240/hiding-map-annotations-without-deleting-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MKAnnotationView`, being a subclass of `UIView`, has a `hidden` property. Just filter your `mapView.annotations` based on the UI and apply a `true` value to that property.